# Query in Firebase - Cloud databese

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on developing one Android application and I have decided that I want to save the data in Firebase. Currently I have one obstacle with loading the data.
First off all I would like to show the architecture of application:

[image: Architecture of application]

In method `OnCreate` is created the instance of *FirebaseHandler* (it is singleton class). After the instance exist, MainActivity call method *nameOfMember*.

```
 public void nameOfMember() {
    DocumentReference documentReference = db.document(pathTOOffersPrefix + userID);
    Log.d(TAG, "nameOfMember: " + pathTOOffersPrefix + userID);

    documentReference.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String name = documentSnapshot.getString(ARG_Firebase_User_Name);
                        String surname = documentSnapshot.getString(ARG_Firebase_User_SurName);
                        setName(name);
                        setSurname(name);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + name + " " + surname);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: but not exist");
                    }

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
}
```

This method setUp two argument of FirebaseHandler instance (for future using). It is working but now come the problem. In *Main.java* I try to get this argument:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firebaseHandler = FirebaseHandler.getInstance();
        firebaseHandler.getName();
        firebaseHandler.getSurname();
}
```

The Main problem is, that the method Main.onCreate will be finisihed earlier than FirebaseHandler.onSuccess.

I would like to ask, if anybody know how to solve it (some callback? or).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is normal behavior of background processing since the Firebase Database functions are executed inside a separate thread, then you need to do the following:

1. Create an `interface` to be a listener for the `getString()` method:

   ```
   public interface OnValueReadyListener {
       void onValueReady(String name, String surName);
   }
   ```
2. Pass an instance of the interface to the `nameOfMember` method:

   ```
   public void nameOfMember(OnValueReadyListener listener) {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Inside the `onSuccess` method, call the listener:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
       if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
           String name = documentSnapshot.getString(ARG_Firebase_User_Name);
           String surname = documentSnapshot.getString(ARG_Firebase_User_SurName);
           listener.onValueReady(name, surname);
           Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + name + " " + surname);
       } else {
           Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: but not exist");
       }

   }
   ```
4. Call the method `nameOfMember` from the `onCreate` as following:

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       firebaseHandler = FirebaseHandler.getInstance();
       firebaseHandler.nameOfMember(new OnValueReadyListener() {
            public void onValueReady(String name, String surName) {
                // Do what you need here. you have the values ready
            }
       });

   }
   ```

Comment: It was implemented and it's work !!!

Thank you very much